# pcap_dispatch() always returns 0 on Mac OSX for wifi interface

Tags: macos, pcap, libpcap, arp

I have few devices connected to wifi router, but pcap_dispatch() always returns 0 for wifi interface while live capturing on Mac OS X. The same code captures response in case of wired interface. Please clarify if I have missed any flag here.

Comment: Are you using a capture filter?

Comment: Yes. I am filtering similar to ethernet: ether dst 70:73:cb:c1:7c:61 and (arp or (ether[14:4]=0xaaaa0300 and ether[20:2]=0x0806) or (ether[12:2]=0x8100 and ether[16:2]=0x0806) or (ether[12:2]=0x8100 and ether[18:4]=0xaaaa0300 and ether[24:2]=0x0806))

Comment: Are you capturing in monitor mode or not in monitor mode?

Comment: I have set monitor mode. pcap_set_rfmon()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are capturing in monitor mode, you will be getting native 802.11 packets, which do *not* look like Ethernet packets, so filtering similarly to Ethernet will *not* work.

Furthermore, if you're capturing in monitor mode on a protected network, i.e. a network using WEP or WPA/WPA2, everything past the 802.11 header will be encrypted, and you will *not* be able to filter on it.

So:

- if you're on an unprotected network, try a filter such as

`wlan dst 70:73:cb:c1:7c:61 and (arp or (vlan and arp))`

- if you're on a protected network, try a filter such as `wlan dst 70:73:cb:c1:7c:61`, and make sure the program that reads the packets either just blindly writes them out to a capture file or is capable of decrypting WEP or WPA/WPA2 packets (the only program I know of that can decrypt them is Wireshark, although some others might be able to do it as well).